# What's the difference?

Tags: python, list

I was doing a list related problem and I stumbled upon this code

```
 l = [1,2,3,4,5]

 a = str(l)[1:-1]

 b = l[1:-1]
```

Why did variable `a` printed the whole list?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, your question isn't very clear. Please read [ask], then [edit] your question accordingly. _Specifically_, what is happening that you don't expect? Note that there's no `print` in your code, so nothing is being printed. I guess the variable `a` has a value you don't expect? What value does it have? What do you expect?

Comment: To understand a complex expression, break it down. First look at what `str(l)` is, THEN you should be able to figure out what the `[1:-1]` is doing.

Comment: What do you mean by `why`? What were you expecting to happen instead? Is there a specific part of it you don't understand at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you cast a list into string in python it returns the elements with the parenthesis '[ ]' so

```py
a = str(l)
```

will give a = '[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]'
and when you get the substring of a from 1st to -1st index it will give you all the elements without the parenthesis because you truncated them.

Answer (score 2):

`str(list)` returns a printable form of the list `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

`[1:-1]` removes the first and last index of the string i.e. `[` and `]`.

So the variable a is now `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` that is a string and not a list of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Because it casts the list l to a string, then removes the first and last characters, which are "[" and "]".